# edit row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to help me with my code. I have 2 gridviews. In the first gridview the user can choose with a checkbox every row he wants. These rows are transfered in the second gridview. All these my code does them well.Now, I want to edit the quantity column in second gridview to change the value but i don't know what i must write in edit box.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;

public partial class ShowLand : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindPrimaryGrid();
            BindSecondaryGrid();

        }
    }
    private void BindPrimaryGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "select * from Land";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        gridview2.DataSource = dt;
        gridview2.DataBind();
    }



    private void GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (ViewState["SelectedRecords1"] != null)
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords1"];
        else
            dt = CreateDataTable();
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gridview2.HeaderRow
                            .Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridview2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkAll.Checked)
            {
                dt = AddRow(gridview2.Rows[i], dt);
            }
            else
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridview2.Rows[i]
                                .Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    dt = AddRow(gridview2.Rows[i], dt);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = RemoveRow(gridview2.Rows[i], dt);
                }
            }
        }
        ViewState["SelectedRecords1"] = dt;
    }
    private void SetData()
    {
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gridview2.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
        chkAll.Checked = true;
        if (ViewState["SelectedRecords1"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords1"];
            for (int i = 0; i < gridview2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridview2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
                if (chk != null)
                {
                    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = '" + gridview2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
                    chk.Checked = dr.Length > 0;
                    if (!chk.Checked)
                    {
                        chkAll.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
            private DataTable CreateDataTable()
                {
                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                     dt.Columns.Add("id");
                     dt.Columns.Add("name");
                     dt.Columns.Add("price");
                     dt.Columns.Add("quantity");
                     dt.Columns.Add("total");
                     dt.AcceptChanges();
                     return dt;
                }
    private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
     {
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
    if (dr.Length <= 0)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["id"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["name"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["price"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["quantity"] = gvRow.Cells[4].Text;
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["total"] = gvRow.Cells[5].Text;
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
    return dt;
    }

    private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
    {
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
    if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
        dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
    return dt;
    }

    protected void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    GetData();
    SetData();
    BindSecondaryGrid();
    }

    private void BindSecondaryGrid()
    {
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords1"];
    gridview3.DataSource = dt;
    gridview3.DataBind(); 
    }
  }
```

and the source code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"
                  AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"
               AutoPostBack = "true"  OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
           ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" 
           SortExpression="name" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="quantity" 
           SortExpression="quantity" />

  <asp:BoundField DataField="total" HeaderText="total" SortExpression="total" />
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Land]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  <br />
  </div>
<div>

<asp:GridView ID="gridview3" runat="server"
  AutoGenerateColumns = "False" DataKeyNames="id" 
  EmptyDataText = "No Records Selected" >
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "id" HeaderText = "id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "name" HeaderText = "name" ReadOnly="True" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "price" HeaderText = "price" 
         DataFormatString="{0:c}" ReadOnly="True" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="quantity">
  <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity")%>'</asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "total" HeaderText = "total" 
            DataFormatString="{0:c}" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Label ID="totalLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />

     </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @adatapost, it's never shameful to ask for help. The guy didn't ask anyone to do his homework. He is learning how to use gridviews step by step. Don't be harsh on people while you can provide some encouragement.

Comment: @deadlock - I'm not against doing homework if he/she is really willing to join the discussion. Pasting unformatted code/text will not serves the purpose of Q&A.

Comment: now, i see your comments. Finally I found the solution. And of course I didn;t want to do my homework.Just to help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not particular asp.net solution but that's how I do something like this in my Windows app.

First of all you shoul make shure that there's a selected row in your GridView (`gridView.SelectedRow != null`). `DataTable` object allows you to get access to desired row by accessing it not by numeric index but by `DataRow`-type object index. After getting a reference to the row which fields' value you want to modify just go ahead with changes.

Here's the example:

```
if (gridView.SelectedRow != null)
{
    dataTable.Rows[gridView.SelectedRow].BeginEdit();
    dataTable.Rows[gridView.SelectedRow]["yourFieldName"] = newValue;
    dataTable.Rows[gridView.SelectedRow].EndEdit();
    gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Hope my answer is of any help because I've never dealt with asp.net before.